How to maximize the minimum of $4$ variables?
How do I maximize this function? Excel solver is unable to solve this.

$$\LARGE \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
& \# & \text{Efficiency} & \text{Total Vol} \\
\hline
\text{A} & 100 & 1000 & 100000 \\
\hline
\text{B} & 50 & 1500 & 75000 \\
\hline
\text{C} & 40 & 2000 & 80000 \\
\hline
\text{D} & 30 & 3500 & 105000 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

The maximum volume possible is $75000$.
$$\text{Total volume for each function} = \text{Count} \times \text{Efficiency}.$$
The maximum volume possible is the minimum of the total volume of each function.
Variables that can be changed are count of each function; the constraint is that the sum of all $4$ needs to be less than $220$.
How can I maximize the 'Max Vol Possible'?

Are there any constraints on the values of count? Are the efficiency values fixed for $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$? Please add these details.

The count of A, B, C, D cannot exceed sum of A,B,C,D
No other constraint
Function A, B, C,D can be considered an assembly line. Minimum volume from any function will be the bottleneck. Need to maximize that

Yup, can only change # column to reallocate count. And sum of all 4 cannot exceed 220

It is best when the four total values are equal, so that none of them is more of a bottleneck than the other. So you want $10a=15b=20c=35d$ and $a+b+c+d=220$. That doesn't have an integer solution, but you can round down $a$ and $b$ (the two least efficient ones) and round up $c$ and $d$.

@JaapScherphuis It is strictly better to round down $a$ only and round up the others.

@RobPratt But wouldn't their sum then exceed 220?

@JaapScherphuis $89+60+45+26=220$

@RobPratt Oh right. I had misjudged the size of the fractional parts.

$\min(\text{Total Vol})$ will be maximum when each row of $\text{Total Vol}$ is equal
For this, the counts ($\#$) must be in the ratio $\frac{1}{1000}:\frac{1}{1500}:\frac{1}{2000}:\frac{1}{3500}$, i.e., $42:28:21:12$
Since $\sum\#=220$, we get counts ($\#$) $\approx$ $89.71$, $59.81$, $44.85$, and $25.63$ for $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ respectively.
As you can see, these aren't integers, hence Excel solver was unable to solve this.
You can round these results to suit your purpose.

Thank you so much
